# Was Rocky Horror Picture Show based on a play?

Tags: rocky-horror-picture-show

Was Rocky Horror Picture Show originally a play?

Answer (score 14):

Well, a stage musical, rather than a play.  [*The Rocky Horror Show*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rocky_Horror_Show) (no "*Picture*") was first staged in London in 1973, with Tim Curry, Little Nell, Patricia Quinn and Richard O'Brien all in the cast.  The movie was released in 1975.

Comment: ... and since a movie is a Picture Show ...